# Работа с typeof

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная которая принимает значение от пользователя (должен принимать число)

Сделал я это так (унарный + чтобы на выходе получать число):

```
let a = +prompt('Write number', 0);
```

Делаю проверку на то что это число :

```
if ( (typeof a == "number") //какой-то код
```

*Проблема в том что если даже я введу строку, то оно все равно передается как число.*
Если убрать унарный `+`, то условие в любом случае будет `false`.

**Мне нужно в переменную `a` передать число и проверить ее на `number`, в противном случае если я ввел строку, условие не должно выполниться.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно написать вот такую функцию, используя как фундамент особенности поведения функции [isNaN](https://webformyself.com/nan-v-javascript/).

```js
const a = '1';
const b = NaN;
const c = 0;
const d = 'Infinity';
const e = 'not number';

function isNum(num) {
  // Если NaN тоже считать числом, то:
  // return Number.isNaN(num) || !isNaN(num)
  return !isNaN(num);
}

console.log(isNum(a)); // '1' -            true
console.log(isNum(b)); // NaN -            false
console.log(isNum(c)); // 0 -              true
console.log(isNum(d)); // 'Infinity' -     true
console.log(isNum(e)); // 'not a number' - false
```

Comment: Спасибо я понял, и ниже ответил

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел как можно проверить переменную на не числовое значение.

```
if ( ( typeof a == "number") && !( isNaN(money)) //какой-то код
```